# How to enable the radio button for below case in angular

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular7

I am using below table... I want to enable the radio button(right side) based on checking the checkbox(left).
When we uncheck the checkbox we want to disable the radio btn.

[image]

```
         <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Select</th>
                  <th>
                    Group Name
                  </th>
                  <th>Profile</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="tabl">
                <tr *ngFor="let data of col; let i = index">
                  <td>
                    <input class="pull-left" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="{{data.id}}"
                      (change)="dataCheck($event,data)" />
                  </td>
                  <td> {{data.name}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="profile" name="profile" 
                       (click)="applyProfile(data.id,data.name)">
                  </td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
```

For checking the checkbox,

```
  dataCheck(event, data) {
      if (event.target.checked) {
         this.selectedGroups.push(data.id);
          console.log("selectedGroups push", this.selectedGroups);
      } else {
         this.selectedGroups = this.selectedGroups.filter(item => {
         item !== data.id;
      });

     }
   }
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: can anybody help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iupjey) is a stackblitz of the working code. I simplified it a bit and left out implementations for the 2 functions defined in the HTML since they weren't necessary for the answer.

```
<tbody id="tabl">

    <tr *ngFor="let data of col; let i = index">
      <td>
        <input #checkboxInput class="pull-left" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="{{data.id}}"
          (change)="dataCheck($event,data)" />
      </td>
      <td> {{data.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" [disabled] = '!checkboxInput.checked' value="profile" name="profile" 
            (click)="applyProfile(data.id,data.name)">
      </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

The idea is to use template referencing on the checkbox since this is the element that we want to see if it is checked or not. `#checkboxInput` exposes the checkbox as an `HTMLInputElement` that we can use as a variable throughout the rest of the HTML. You can read more about what properties are exposed on `HTMLInputElement` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Only checkboxes and radio buttons have the `checked` property. So, on the radio button, we set `[disabled] = !checkboxInput.checked` as an attribute. This is saying "If the checkbox is not checked, then the radio button is disabled. If the checkbox is checked, then the radio button is not disabled".

Hopefully this helps.